# Compare 2 dataframes on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

So, I have 2 dataframes like:

```
DataframeA:

ID,CLASS,DIVISION
1,123,3G
2,456,5G
3,123,4G


DataframeB:

ID,CLASS,DIVISION
1,123,3G
2,456,4G
```

I would like to **substract** `DataframeA` from `DataframeB` such that, only the **records that are in `DataframeA` and not in `DataframeB` should be present**. But the **comparison should be on `CLASS` and `DIVISION` columns only**.

```
Expected Output:

ID,CLASS,DIVISION
2,456,5G
3,123,4G
```

Now I can do a Left-Join between `DataframeA` and `DataframeB` on `[CLASS, DIVISION]` and then select only the `isNull` values of `CLASS, DIVISION` columns of `DataframeB` like so:

```
new_df = pd.merge(DataframeA, DataframeB, how='left', left_on=fileA_headerList, right_on=fileB_headerList)
new_df = new_df[new_df[fileB_headerList].isnull().all(axis=1)]
```

But I would like to know whether there's a more **Elegant** or **Pythonic** way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True`

```
res = pd.merge(df1,df2[['CLASS','DIVISION']],on=['CLASS','DIVISION'],how='outer',indicator=True)
res =res[res['_merge']=='left_only'].drop(['_merge'],axis=1)
print(res)
```

```
    ID  CLASS DIVISION     
1  2.0    456       5G  
2  3.0    123       4G
```

Answer (score 0):

With `left` *join* (`df1` - left frame, `df2` - right frame) and filtering out matched rows:

```
In [1157]: df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=df1.columns.drop('ID').tolist(), how='left', suffixes=('', '_'))

In [1158]: df3[df3['ID_'].isna()].drop('ID_', axis=1)
Out[1158]: 
   ID  CLASS DIVISION
1   2    456       5G
2   3    123       4G
```